# referencing methods in other files

Tags: java, android, oop, methods

I am trying to use the `getPermissiontoReadSMS` and `onRequestPermissionsResult` methods in the `permissionsSMSHelper` class. When I reference them in the n`ewMessagePage.java` file and the `onCreate` method of the `homePage.java` file, it gives me the "cannot resolve method" error everytime. I cannot figure out what is wrong. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

**permisssionsSMSHelper.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class permissionsSMSHelper extends homePage {

public int READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST;

public permissionsSMSHelper(int req) {
    READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = req;
}

public void getPermissionToReadSMS(int reqVal) {
    READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = reqVal;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, reqVal);
    }
}

public RequestPermissionsResult(int req) {
    READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = req;
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       int requestNum,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST= requestNum;

    if(requestCode == requestNum) {
        if(grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            refreshSmsInbox();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

**homePage.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
        messages.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            permissionsSMSHelper SMScheck = new permissionsSMSHelper(1);

            SMScheck.getPermissionToReadSMS(1);
            SMScheck.onRequestPermissionsResult(1);

        }else {
            refreshSmsInbox();
        }

        addDrawerItems();
        FABListener();
    }
```

**newMessagePage.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class newMessagePage extends homePage {

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
EditText input;

public void onSendClick(View view) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        permissionsSMSHelper SMScheck = new permissionsSMSHelper(1);

        SMScheck.getPermissionToReadSMS(1);
        SMScheck.onRequestPermissionsResult(1);

    }else {

        smsManager.sendTextMessage("17739965441", null, input.getText().toString(), null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message_page);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Your so called `PermissionsSMSHelper` class is extending `HomePage` and you are creating an instance of `permissionsSMSHelper` in `HomePage` and that and also in the case of `NewMessagePage` you are indirectly referencing an activity inside another class and that will result in a memory leak . Remove the `extends homePage` from `PermissionsSMSHelper` and pass a `Context` in the constructor or make the methods static inside PermissonsSMSHelper and pass Context in every method call. **Your Naming convention is TOO BAD**